# Visual Studio Code g++ does not compile with c++17 when debugging

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, g++

I want to compile the active file in the current workspace folder.

With a C++11 file there is no problem I just hit run->start debugging and the right `launch.json` and `tasks.json` is generated.

However with a file which contains C++17 code I run in trouble.

I thought adding the flag `-std=c++17` in `tasks.json` would compile on debugging with C++17 but it does not work.

Here the configuration files:

**launch.jsons**

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++ - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        }
    ]
}
```

**tasks.json**

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-std=c++17",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Generated task by Debugger"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

From my understanding the following should happen:

When I start the debugger first the file should be compiled with the command:

```
"preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
```

in `launch.json`.

In `tasks.json` this task is defined to call g++ with C++17 flag':

```
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-std=c++17",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
```

Still when run this it looks like the task is executed without C++17 compilation. I get this error:

> Executing task: C/C++: g++ build active file <
>
> ```
> Starting build...
> Build finished with error:
>
> /...Solution2.cpp:48:10: error: ‘optional’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type
>    48 |     std::optional<Stack> getLastStack() const;
>       |          ^~~~~~~~
> ```

To verify the compiler works just compiled the file from command line with

```
g++ -std=c++17 Solution2.cpp
```

And run it from command line with:

```
./a.out
```

My system is Manjaro Linux.

g++ (GCC) 10.2.0

VSCode 1.15.1

Comment: Does your compiler support `c++17`?

Comment: To be honest I would have expected the same. Can you get the complete compiler command line generated by the IDE? They usually stash it somewhere if for no better reason than troubleshooting problems like this. Mare sure the `-std=c++17` is making it to the compiler.

Comment: On command line it just compiles fine with g++ -std=++17. How can I get the complete command line?

Comment: Really dumb question, but are you sure that ```#include <optional>``` is in there somewhere (when you're not compiling through command line)?

Comment: yes `#include <optional>` is present. And why should it compile via command line then if it would be not?

Comment: In Manjaro, use QtCreator or CLion for C++ ;-) Or switch to cmake in Visual Studio Code - this should be possible - and enjoy portable compilation workflow. But this does not answer your question...

Comment: Are you sure `tasks.json` is used by VSC? Perhaps try to break the syntax in it and see what happens. Or just rename it - will VSC complain?

Comment: Have you tried this: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference ? According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/integrate-build-task?view=azure-devops, `tasks.json` controls pipelines, so its purpose may be not what you think it is.

Comment: I think it doesn't use tasks.json for compiling!

Comment: I'm aware that I could use QtCreator or CMake and use it for bigger projects and Qt but for a quick and dirty small program I thought VSCode with its default is usually enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like there is "built-in" task with name "C/C++: g++ build active file", so that even if it's not defined in `tasks.json` but used in `launch.json`, it is launched anyway... with some default configuration you can't change, of course. Try to remove this task from `tasks.json` to find out that's true.

This built-in task also seems to have higher priority than the one defined by you. This is probably a bug in VSC, but simple workaround with changing task name seems to be doing the job.

Just rename your task to something else that default name. Ie your `tasks.json` would look like this (notice how `label` key is defined):

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "Totally custom debug task name",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-std=c++17",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Generated task by Debugger"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

And your `launch.json` - like this (notice how `preLaunchTask` is defined):

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++ - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "Totally custom debug task name",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This totally solved my issue. did not come to my mind that there some default task with the same name hiding the one in the task file. I wonder if this default task can be edited.

Comment: Like I said it's probably built-in, and this behavior you encountered is just a bug. Similar to this: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/111048 - I went ahead and commented about the issue you ran into, since it looks like it has the same source, so let's hope the devs will take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem like you, but I have solved it easily. You just need to add `"-std=c++17",` after `"-g",` in `tasks.json` file and don't need to do anything.
This is content of my `tasks.json` file:

```
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "-std=c++17",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": "build"
    },
```

This is content of my `launch.json` file:

```
{
        "name": "Linux C/C++ Debug",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
        "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
    },
```